# How do I enable systemd units to run at first boot?

Tags: 18.04, systemd, debootstrap, systemd-networkd

I have a bionic image built using debootstrap. I have neither netplan nor NetworkManager installed, but networkd does not start at boot.

```
# grep networkd /lib/systemd/system-preset/90-systemd.preset
enable systemd-networkd.service
```

[image]

Do I need to manually create a symlink in my image from `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-networkd.service` to `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service`?

And similarly for some one-shot units of my own that need to run at first boot (actually generated in the initramfs)?

Comment: See [ConditionFirstBoot=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#ConditionArchitecture=)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out, but it sounds like exactly the thing I need.

Comment: On second reading, it looks like this predicates the unit so that it *only* runs on first boot.

Comment: Exactly. I thought that was what you were asking for.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to *make* it run on first boot. Currently it doesn't run on *any* boot unless I run `systemctl enable`. I need the system to come up with it already running, and then run on every subsequent boot too.

Answer (score 0):

No manual linking is needed, all is done by systemctl. When you look at your output it shows service is disabled. Enable it with `systemctl enable systemd-networkd` That will allow it to run after reboot.

Comment: I can't run `systemctl` until *after* the *first* boot. I want it to already be running by then.